# How to stop curl command executing through jruby code?

Tags: curl, jruby, jrubyonrails

I am having following code in my model methods which i am calling from my controller.

`Kernel.system"curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{\"party\":{\"lock_version\":\"0\",\"party_type\":\"Customer\",\"name\":\"xxxxx\",\"sub_type\":\"\",\"description\":\"\",\"contacts_attributes\":{\"1\":{\"name\":\"Jy\",\"email\":\"xxxx@gmail.com\",\"is_default\":\"true\",\"_destroy\":\"0\"}}}}" "http://localhost:3000/company/customers?auth_token=BhD7P6sXkHkNwVVXx3TF""`

when the above code execute,on console i can see.

`% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   202    0     0    0   202      0      0 --:--:--  0:04:13 --:--:--     0`

but the above process is keep going on.When i shutdown my server using `CTRL+c` i can see the following lines on my console.

`Started POST "/company/customers?auth_token=BhD7P6sXkHkNwVVXx3TF" for 127.0.0.1 at Mon Nov 26 05:24:13 +0000 2012
  Processing by PartiesController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"party"=>{"lock_version"=>"0", "party_type"=>"Customer", "name"=>"xxxxx", "sub_type"=>"", "description"=>"", "contacts_attributes"=>{"1"=>{"name"=>"Jy", "email"=>"xxxx@gmail.com", "is_default"=>"true", "_destroy"=>"0"}}}, "auth_token"=>"BhD7P6sXkHkNwVVXx3TF", "party_type"=>"Customer"}
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity`

Which means that my `customer` is successfully using `curl`.

But why do i need to shutdown my server and then restart inorder to see the result of `curl` command?Is there any solution for this problem or am i doing something wrong?

Please help me,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got answer to my question.
I just had to use `-m` command which limit the execution time for command.

like

`Kernel.system"curl -m 3 -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{\"party\":{\"lock_version\":\"0\",\"party_type\":\"Customer\",\"name\":\"xxxxx\",\"sub_type\":\"\",\"description\":\"\",\"contacts_attributes\":{\"1\":{\"name\":\"Jy\",\"email\":\"xxxx@gmail.com\",\"is_default\":\"true\",\"_destroy\":\"0\"}}}}" "http://localhost:3000/company/customers?auth_token=BhD7P6sXkHkNwVVXx3TF""`

Which will run for 3 sec...so now i do not need to shutdown my server.:-)